# What does “Bartlett’s Best” mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I’m drawn to the word, “Bartlett’s best” appearing in the following paragraph of Washington Post’s (May 13) article titled, “A theory: Trump fired Comey because he’s taller.”:

> “Trump’s daily scrimmages with the English language make Bushisms seem
>   like “**Bartlett’s Best**.” When not syntactically challenged, they’re
>   jaw-droppingly mystifying. What possibly could Trump have intended
>   when he suggested to NBC’s Lester Holt that he doesn’t know for sure
>   if there’s an FBI investigation into “this Russia thing”? So the
>   president doesn’t believe what every intelligence agency has said and
>   what he has personally been told in briefings?

https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/a-theory-trump-fired-comey-because-hes-taller/2017/05/12/ca2378f0-3751-11e7-b373-418f6849a004_story.html?hpid=hp_no-name_opinion-card-

I understand “Bushism” is G.W. Bush’s particular parlance, but I don’t understand what “Trump’s daily scrimmages makes Bushisms seem like “**Bartlett’s best**” means.

Does it simply mean Mr. Trump’s "English language" is poorer than that of Mr. Bush?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartlett%27s_Familiar_Quotations): 'Bartlett's Familiar Quotations, often simply called Bartlett's, is an American reference work that is the longest-lived and most widely distributed collection of quotations. The book was first issued in 1855 and is currently in its eighteenth edition, published in 2012.' Hence, a selection of choice quotes.

Comment: 'Bartlett' may be a Hebrew boy's name, but I have never heard of it as a first name for Americans/British/Jews/Israelis modern or ancient. Where did you get that impression?

Comment: There's no Hebrew here at all. Where do people get these ideas??

Comment: @Mitch.@Lambie. I mistakingly referred to www.sheknows.com/baby-names which says: The name Bartlett is a Hebrew baby name. In Hebrew the meaning of the name Bartlett is: Ploughman, and a separate  source stating "Son of Talmai Diminutive of Bartholomew, Hebrew, "son of the earth." Clearly they seem irrelevant to the word,“Bartlett’s best.” So I crossed out the previous reference to Hebrew relevance from the post. My apology  for making loose check.

Comment: Most name origins on the internet are pretty terrible. The only general-reference I know if that's pretty reliable is [Behind The Name](https://www.behindthename.com), which is generally pretty good, at least for Western European and biblical names. Unfortunately, it doesn't have an official entry for Bartlett, but it does say that [Bartholomew](http://www.behindthename.com/name/bartholomew) comes from "the Greek form of an Aramaic name meaning "son of [TALMAI](http://www.behindthename.com/name/talmai)"", which is actually ancient Hebrew, so there may be Hebrew roots waaaay down the line.

Comment: @Lambie there is some Hebrew here. The family name Bartlett came into English from French at the Norman Conquest in 1066, and the French was originally a derivative of Bartholomew. The "Bar" prefix  means "Son of" in Hebrew, and Bartholomew is a Biblical name, though it only occurs in the (Greek) New Testament not the (Hebrew) Old Testament. But AFAIK it was only a *family* name in English, not a *given* name - though of course modern Americans give their kids all manner of strange names!

Comment: The perspective to have of this, fro 1006a's and alephzero's comments is that you're getting the wrong impression from these dictionaries. Bartholomew is not uncommon as a given name in the US, but people with this name are almost always called 'Bart'. but is not considered Hebrew nowadays at all.

Comment: I visited that website page, and it says [Bartlett, ploughman **Origin**: French, English, Hebrew](http://www.sheknows.com/baby-names/search/bartlett) It doesn't specifically say it is Hebrew.

Comment: There are names that are immediately Hebrew: Aaron, Sarah, Isaiah etc. But for the quotations' book, it's meaningless in terms of the question posed here. The question was not about the name origin. :)

Answer (score 14):

It's a reference to [*Bartlett's Familiar Quotations*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartlett%27s_Familiar_Quotations), the classic collection of quotable quotes. It was first published in the mid-1800s, and has been pretty much continuously in print ever since. Before there was the internet, if you needed a pithy epigraph or wanted to know "who said that" you turned to *Bartlett's*.

The implication of the line here is that the things Trump says are so unintelligible that George W. Bush's previously-ridiculed utterances sound brilliantly quotable in comparison.